# Fourier transform of a sinusoidal function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

Let us consider following table which I want to calculate  myself

$$
x(t)=\frac{\sin(\omega_bt)}{\pi t}\quad\iff\quad X(j\omega)= 
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if $|\omega|<\omega_b$}, \\[8pt]
    0 & \text{if $|\omega|>\omega_b$}.
  \end{cases}
$$
I want to prove it myself, so I have tried

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{j\omega_bt}-e^{-j\omega_bt}) e^{j\omega t}}{2j\pi t}\ dt$$

now separately

$$e^{j \omega_b t} e^{j\omega t}=e^{j t(\omega_b+\omega)}$$
and
$$e^{-j \omega_b t} e^{j\omega t}=e^{-j t(\omega_b+\omega)}$$

How can I continue from this? Thanks.

Comment: The easiest methods that come to mind are a) to compute the inverse Fourier transform of $X(j\omega)$, and b) to evaluate the Fourier integral with the residue theorem.

Comment: i am taking inverse fourier ,but does not work,it does not gives me  time  domain function

Comment: The inverse Fourier transform leads to an integral $$C\cdot \int_{-\omega_b}^{\omega_b} 1\cdot e^{\pm j\omega t}\,d\omega,$$ where the factor $C$ and the sign of the exponent depend on the used convention for the Fourier transform. You can evaluate that integral explicitly, and obtain $\tilde{C}\frac{\sin (\omega_b t)}{t}$ as the inverse Fourier transform. Check that $\tilde{C} = \frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: @datodatuashvili: Your integral should be $dt$, not $d\omega$.

Comment: yes last one is necessary when we are taking inverse Fourier transform